# Fiber functors and artinian categories

Tags: category-theory, algebraic-groups

I am not sure if this is a trivial result. Is it true that if an abelian monoidal category $\tilde{\mathfrak{C}}$ admits a fibre functor then each object of the underlying abelian category $\mathfrak{C}$ is artinian and noetherian? Why? Or maybe a weaker result, are tannakian categories also artinian and noetherian? Why?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a fibre functor? Is it a functor to the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of small sets?

Comment: @user24453 it is an exact and faithful monoidal functor from $\tilde{\mathfrak{C}}$ to the category of $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: By the "associated category", do you just mean the underlying abelian category (forgetting the monoidal structure)? Also, must the fibre functor take values in *finite dimensional* vector spaces?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, I mean the underlying abelian category. And yes, it must take values in the category of finite dimensional vector spaces. Let met precise all that info. What happens if it goes to the category of not necessarily finite dimensional vector spaces anyway?

Comment: If you allow infinite dimensional values, then you could just take $\tilde{\mathfrak{C}}$ to be the category of (not necessarily finite dimensional) vector spaces, with the identity functor as fibre functor. Then any infinite dimensional vector space is an object of $\tilde{\mathfrak{C}}$ that is neither artinian nor noetherian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be the fibre functor. If $f:X\to Y$ is a monomorphism, but not an epimorphism, in $\mathfrak{C}$, then $Ff:FX\to FY$ is a monomorphism of vector spaces by exactness, but not an epimorphism since otherwise the identity map on $\text{cok}f$ would be sent to zero, contradicting faithfulness.

So if an object $X$ of $\mathfrak{C}$ has a chain
$$0=X_0<X_1<\dots<X_n=X$$
of subobjects, each a proper subobject of the next, then applying $F$ we get a chain of monomorphisms, but not epimorphisms, of vector spaces
$$0=FX_0\to FX_1\to\dots\to FX_n=FX,$$
which is impossible if $\dim FX<n$.

So if $\dim FX<\infty$ then $X$ cannot have an infinite chain, descending or ascending, of subobjects, so $X$ is artinian and noetherian.